# ggplot coord_polar() plotting between pi/2 and -pi/2 at top and bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2, radians

I have a set of values that range between pi/2 and -pi/2. I'd like to plot them using the histogram geom and polar plot, so at the top of the polar there is pi/2 and at the bottom, there is -pi/2.

The datafile I'm using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9npm6whxi9ok5d/ellipse_df.csv?dl=0

```
ggplot(ellipse_df) +
  geom_histogram(aes(theta)) +
  coord_polar(start = pi/2, direction = -1)
```

There seems to be something funny with the pinching of the x axis on the left of the plot below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`. `ggplot` automatically pads a bit on each end of all the scales so there's a nice border around a plot, but in polar coordinates, you usually want it to wrap with no gap.

---

### Updated with additional steps to neaten the appearance:

```
  ggplot(ellipse_df, aes(theta/(pi))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .05, colour = "white", boundary = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = -2:2/4, 
                     labels = c(expression(frac(-pi, 2)), 
                                expression(frac(-pi, 4)), 
                                "0", 
                                expression(frac(+pi, 4)), 
                                expression(frac(+pi, 2)))) +
  coord_polar(start = pi/2, direction = -1)
```

If you run this **without** the arguments to `geom_histogram` and **without** `coord_polar`, you can diagnose what's going on:

[image]

The default 30 bins leaves one at the upper edge of the data with very few observations. By forcing the bins to have a certain width and choosing whether 0 is the center or edge, you can force the bins to line up neatly with the range of your data.

[image]

Then when you convert it to polar coordinates, it looks how you want, I assume:

[image]

---

### Updated to change scale to equal radians

To get the -pi/2 to pi/2 to be the right half of the circle, you need to expand the x limits quite a bit:

```
  ... +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), 
                     breaks = c(-4, -2:2, 4)/4, 
                     limits = c(-1, 1),           # this is the important change
                     labels = c(expression(-pi),
                                expression(frac(-pi, 2)), 
                                expression(frac(-pi, 4)), "0", 
                                expression(frac(+pi, 4)),
                                expression(frac(+pi, 2)),
                                expression(+pi))) + ...
```

Since (after scaling by pi), your data go from -1/2 to 1/2, but you want the figure to display -1 to 1, you have to tell it to display all that non-data space.

[image]

[image]

If your next question is: how can I show it just as a semicircle, without the wasted space on the left? I'll preemptively answer that it's more challenging and will involve precalculating your histogram values and converting the corners of each bar to polar coordinates "by hand".

Comment: I get the same output when I add `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`. I tried messing with `scale_x_continuous()` and its parameters, but I cannot get it right.

Comment: @HLudwig, check out my edits. It's always good to view polar plots in cartesian coordinates first to be able to diagnose problems.

Comment: Hi Brian! Wow, thank you. I am looking to have the data only display on the right hemisphere of the plot. Since the data are representing radians from pi/2 to -pi/2. In other words, the data values show angles between 90 degrees and -90 degrees. So, was the binning problem a result of values that are pi/2 and -pi/2 being the same?

Comment: just forgot to ping, @Brian

Comment: @HLudwig like that?

Comment: Bingo! :) Many thanks! I would not have gotten the limits to be 1 and -1.